# Windows-7 snap Windows-left/right doesn't work fully for console (command-prompt) in dual monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, console, aero-snap

1. Start>Run>cmd
2. Select the command shell window
3. Use windows-left and -right. Observe that it doesn't go to all four positions (left of left monitor, right of left monitor, left  of right monitor, right of right
   monitor) as you cycle through.
   Any idea how to fix this?

Update 6/9/2011: as @Shinrai asked Monitors have different resolutions, left is 1600x1200, right 1680x1050.

Comment: When I do this, it hits every position.  (Left-left, normal-left, right-left, left-right, normal-right, right-right, then back to left-left) just like every other window.  What resolution and orientation are your monitors?  Are you running any multimon management apps?

Comment: Works for me too (Win 7, 3 monitors); @Brian Carlton - As Shinrai asked - we'd need to know your current monitor setup (etc).

Comment: Same here... works exactly as expected

Comment: My setup (Win7 Enterprise x64) does not snap between screen, only on outer edge. But using the Win+Right or Win+Left keys I can cycle from Left-Left => Left-Center => Left-Right => Right-Left => Right-center => Right-Right. My guess is the x64 platform...

Comment: Works for me too, with different resolution monitors (1920x1200 and 1600x1200). What doesn't work is dragging with the mouse - that only snaps for the far left and right and next to the taskbar (which I have on the left of my rightmost monitor).